# Login with either email or phone in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new in Laravel and I'm developing an application that will require users to log in with either email (minority) or their phone number (majority). Currently I'm using the default Laravel auth with modified registration to allow users to provide their phone number. The solutions I have found are showing how to log in with a username instead of an email. How can I achieve this?. I'm running Laravel 5.2 with PHP 7.0

Here is my User model:

```
protected $fillable = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email','phone','account_type','county','sub_county', 'password',];

protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token',];
```

Here is my AuthenticateUsers.php:

```
 /**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password');
}

/**
 * Validate the user login request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function loginUsername()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';
}
```

Email input field in my login form:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email')    }}">

@if ($errors->has('email'))
<span class="help-block">
<strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
</span>
@endif
</div>
</div>

@if ($errors->has('email'))
<span class="help-block">
<strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
</span>
@endif
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `loginUsername` function, make the following change to check if the request has a phone property before using the email default.

`public function loginUsername($request) {
    return $request->has('phone') ? 'phone' : 'email';
}`

Comment: The `loginUsername()` method doesn't have access to `$request` the way you have it there

Comment: You can pass the request instance to `loginUsername` method since it's available in the calling methods of the `AuthenticateUsers` class.

Comment: I have passed the `$request` parameter to the `loginUsername()` function and also changed it in ThrottlesLogins.php to look like this        `protected function getThrottleKey(Request $request)
    {
        return mb_strtolower($request->input($this->loginUsername($request))).'|'.$request->ip();
    }`. With that I was able to login with my email address. How do I modify my **view/ model/ controller** to accept phone input? @Oluwafemi

Comment: You can make use of another form in your view that has an input with name attribute equal to 'phone'. If you're using just one form, you can validate that the input is an email and when it fails validation, go on to default to using phone. This can be done in the `loginUsername` function.

Comment: I'm getting close but I guess I'm missing something. I'm only able to login with the phone number and not the email. I think the problem is with my view or validation for the email. Login input field ` <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}"> ` `AuthController` `protected $phone='phone';`  and the `loginUsername` function `public function loginUsername($request)
    {
              
        return property_exists($this, filter_var($request->input('phone'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ? 'email' : 'phone';
    }` @OluwafemiSule